# How to test domain-redirect locally in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, dns, hosts

We have a website that is hosted on a domain

```
brand.hostingcompany.com
```

The website has bought a new domain and I wish to point the new domain to that site. I want to test this redirect on my computer running windows 7 before doing it live. I tried adding this to my hosts-file and saving.

```
    example.no      brand.hostingcompany.com
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `example.no` with the ip address of the site that you want to redirect into and it should work.

Comment: I just tried´  127.0.0.1  google.com ´without any success.

Comment: Also, I don't think the ip is gonna work I tried looking it up using https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html and it won't work, the site is used for multiple domains, I need to use the domain name.  brand.hostingcompany.com

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do it with domain name, only with IP,